# Sending struct containing other struct as ZeroMQ message

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, zeromq

I have a problem sending zmq message built from the pointer to struct, which contains other struct.

The server code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace zmq;
using namespace std;

struct structB{
    int a;
    string c;
};

struct structC{
    int z;
    struct structB b;
};

int main()
{
    context_t context(1);
    socket_t *socket = new socket_t(context,ZMQ_REP);
    socket->bind("tcp://*:5555");

    message_t *request = new message_t();   
    socket->recv(request);

    struct structB messageB; 
    messageB.a=0;
    messageB.c="aa";

    struct structC *messageC = new struct structC;
    messageC->z = 4;
    messageC->b = messageB;

    char *buffer = (char*)(messageC);
    message_t *reply = new message_t((void*)buffer,
                       +sizeof(struct structB)
                       +sizeof(struct structC)
                       ,0);
    socket->send(*reply);

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace zmq;

struct structB{
    int a;
    string c;
};

struct structC{
    int z;
    struct structB b;
};

int main()
{ 
    context_t context(1);
    socket_t *socket = new socket_t(context,ZMQ_REQ);
    socket->connect("tcp://*:5555");

    const char* buffer = "abc";
    message_t *request = new message_t((void*)buffer,sizeof(char*),0);
    socket->send(*request);

    message_t *reply = new message_t;
    socket->recv(reply);

    struct structC *messageC = new struct structC;
    messageC = static_cast<struct structC*>(reply->data());

cout<<messageC->b.a<<endl;//no crash here

    struct structB messageB = messageC->b;//Segmentation fault (core dumped)

    return 0;
}
```

This program crashes when I try to use string called "c" from structB. It doesn't matter if I try to print it, or assign whole structB as in above example.

Where is the problem? Should I create message_t *reply on server side in different way?

Comment: You have strange mix of C and C++ syntax (In C, structs are separate namespace and require the `struct` keyword when used, but in C++ they don't. Why do you _sometimes_ use it?) and similarly strange mix of stack and heap allocated objects (Why do you create `messageB` on stack and `messageC` on heap? `messageC` can also be created on stack. And `messageB` is part of `messageC`; you don't need a separate instance.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot send [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented/1466658#1466658) over network as `std::string` is a container. You can use [flexible array member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047530/flexible-array-member-in-c-structure) or big size array or write a small class which is [serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046244/serializing-a-class-which-contains-a-stdstring) (you have to write code by yourself to prepare buffer) to send the data.

When you do `struct structB messageB = messageC->b;`, pointer members of `std::string` member embed inside messageC->b might be dereference in copy constructor or `std::string` which is possibly causing the segmentation fault.

Example of large char array would be:

```
struct structB{
    int a;
    char c[MAX_LENGTH];
};
```

Later

```
struct structB messageB; 
messageB.a=0;
strcpy(messageB.c,"aa"); // #include<cstring> or use std::copy from <algorithm>

struct structC *messageC = new struct structC;
// I guess you want this(not sure) messageC->z = static_cast<int>( sizeof(int) + strlen(messageB) + 1 );
messageC->z = 4;
messageC->b = messageB;
```

And then

```
const int length = sizeof(int) /* z */ + sizeof(int) /* a */ + strlen("aa") + 1;
zmq::message_t msg (length);
memcpy (msg.data (), &messageC, length);
socket->send(msg);
```

These are some changes required at server side, you need to make similar changes at client side also.

As a side note, your code is very messy, don't deploy it in larger applications before sorting out few things like removal of unnecessary `new` and properly representing nested structures.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using something like [Google Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to handle the serialization. It sounds like overkill for playing around, but even throw-away prototypes often end up being used long past their originally expected lifetime and when it grows large or when it needs to change, good serialization library will help a lot in keeping the code maintainable.

Comment: @JanHudec I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Your structures are not POD. Class "string" can't be copied as memory heap. There is a problem.

Use c.c_str() and c.size() to copy in as memory block.